# How to deploy a snapshot artifact to a Maven repository and produce valid maven-metadata.xml using Gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus, maven-metadata

I have the following `build.gradle` script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

compileJava {
    targetCompatibility = "1.8"
    sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

ext.username = System.getProperty('username') != null ? System.getProperty('username') : mavenUser
ext.password = System.getProperty('password') != null ? System.getProperty('password') : mavenPassword

description = "Example project that shows how to use Gradle to build and deploy artifacts to Nexus"

configurations {
    deployerJars
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/my-group/" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

// Gradle build Configuration to publish artifacts to maven artifact manager
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.deployerJars
            repository(url: "http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/my-snapshots/") {
                authentication(userName: username, password: password)
            }
            pom.groupId = "com.foo.bar"
            pom.artifactId = "my-gradle-app"
            pom.version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------
// EXAMPLE: custom tasks for creating source/javadoc jars
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

// add javadoc/source jar tasks as artifacts
artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

When I execute the following, the build and deployment succeeds:

```
$ gradle clean upload -Dusername=myUsername -Dpassword=myPassword
```

The produced `maven-metadata.xml` file looks like this:

```
<metadata>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-gradle-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <versioning>
        <snapshot>
            <timestamp>20170906.143113</timestamp>
            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
        </snapshot>
        <lastUpdated>20170906143113</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

These are the files that have actually been deployed to Nexus:

```
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1-javadoc.jar
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1-javadoc.jar.md5
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1-javadoc.jar.sha1
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1-sources.jar
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1-sources.jar.md5
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1-sources.jar.sha1
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1.jar
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1.jar.md5
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1.jar.sha1
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1.pom
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1.pom.md5
my-gradle-app-1.0-20170906.143113-1.pom.sha1
```

Coming from a Maven background, I am expecting to see the following in the `maven-metadata.xml` file:

```
<metadata>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-gradle-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <versioning>
        <snapshot>
            <timestamp>20170906.143113</timestamp>
            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
        </snapshot>
        <lastUpdated>20170906143113</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
    <snapshotVersions>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.0-20170906.143113-1</value>
            <updated>20170906140847</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.0-20170906.143113-1</value>
            <updated>20170906140847</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.0-20170906.143113-1</value>
            <updated>20170906140844</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>pom</extension>
            <value>1.0-20170906.143113-1</value>
            <updated>20170906140847</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
</metadata>
```

If I re-run the deployment, I would be expecting the `maven-metadata.xml` file to no only have the `<snapshot/>`'s `<timestamp/>` and `<buildNumber>` to be updated, but also to get new `<snapshotVersion/>` entries appended. What's happening instead is, the whole file is regenerated and there's just one `<snapshotVersion/>` and only the `<snapshot/>`'s `<timestamp/>` and `<buildNumber>` are correctly updated.

What am I missing here? Why isn't the `maven-metadata.xml` being produced properly? Is there a plugin that I am missing? Is this a bug in Gradle?

In addition, I have raised issue [#2882](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2882) in the Gradle issue tracker in hope to figure out whether this is a bug, incomplete feature, or a mis-configuration from our side.

I have also tried the `maven-publish` plugin, but the produced `maven-metadata.xml` file is still the same.

Comment: Do you consider using https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html an option?

Comment: Yes, I have and the behavior is the same in regards to the produced `maven-metadata.xml`.

Comment: There is much extended discussion at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2882

Comment: @MarkHu: As you may have noticed, I have mentioned this in my question and it was in fact me who raised and described the issue and illustrated how it needs to be fixed. Unfortunately, it still isn't.